# Why add-apt-repository --remove doesn't remove the ppa list

Tags: ubuntu

I want to remove a ppa, which is a very basic thing. But it seems my ubuntu doesn't work it well. I know there are many similar questions, I proposed something that confusing me but not mentioned nor well-explained in other questions.

I have tried to use 'sudo add-apt-repository --remove' and 'sudo apt-get purge', but none of them work as supposed. The ppa source list file still exist.

**Here is the code:**

First, checked the third-party ppa lists in sources.list.d

```
xx:~$ cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
xx/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ ls
```

The result:

```
artfwo-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list       something else.list
```

Now, assuming **I want to delete the 'artfwo' ppa**.

1. Using apt with --remove:

```
sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:artfwo/ppa

This archive contains SuperCollider packages, some packages, related to bug 217611, libvorbis with aoTuV beta5.5 patchset and test packages of various projects.
More info: https://launchpad.net/~artfwo/+archive/ubuntu/ppa
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel removing it.
(I clicked Enter)
xx:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$
```

Pressed [ENTER] to confirm, nothing happen.
Check the ppa list use 'ls':

```
sudo apt-get update
ls
```

result:

```
artfwo-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list       something else.list
```

**artfwo ppa list still exist!** The more confusing thing is, if use apt --remove again:

```
sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:artfwo/ppa
This archive contains SuperCollider packages, some packages, related to bug 217611, libvorbis with aoTuV beta5.5 patchset and test packages of various projects.
More info: https://launchpad.net/~artfwo/+archive/ubuntu/ppa
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel removing it.
```

It can still found artfwo ppa which just removed by command and still ask me to confirm this removing. So if the apt-add-repository --remove doesn't remove the ppa list, neither can detect removed ppa. What the meaning of it?

2. Using purge

```
sudo apt-get install purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:artfwo/ppa
```

The result:

```
Updating packages lists
PPA to be removed: artfwo ppa
Warning:  Could not find package list for PPA: artfwo ppa
```

**It cannot found artfwo ppa!**

Still, using 'ls' to check ppa lists:

```
sudo apt-get update
ls
```

result:

```
artfwo-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list       something else.list
```

The artfwo ppa list didn't be purged.

I know this might because I had delete it successfully by using apt-add-repository --remove in previous. However, the sources list still exist in sources.list.d and apt-add-repository --remove can still detect it and even ask me again to confirm removing, these things, in the opposite, shows that that ppa still exist.

**Overall:**

1. Why both 'apt-add-repository --remove' and 'ppa-purge' doesn't delete the list file in sources.list.d? It looks annoying for remaining something!
2. Why after used 'apt-add-repository --remove' on a ppa source and confirmed, it can then still been used on the same ppa source again and again? Does the ppa repository be removed really?